# Date field from php to mysql returning error 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php form where I have to manually input a date. When I type the date as Y/M/D I don't have any problem.
But if I enter the date as d/m/y it is stored in my database as 0000-00-00

```
$TransactionDate= $row['DealDate'];
```

TransactionDate = my field name
DealDate = my column name

I need Help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DealDate']);
```

1. If your MySQL column is DATE type:

   ```
   $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
   ```
2. If your MySQL column is DATETIME type:

   ```
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date)));
   ```

if the date seperator is - you cannot use strototime(), because it will not work with dash - separators, it will try to do a subtraction.

in that case use regular expression

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DealDate']);
$date = preg_replace('#(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})\s(.*)#', '$3-$2-$1 $4', $date);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's only acceptable direct-use date format is `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. Inserting anything else will almost always result on a 0000-00-00 default date value being inserted.

If your date string is in some other format, you'll have to massage it into a MySQL-acceptable format first.